# comparing sum of 2 column values in one table with another column value in second table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables...

table1 ( id, item, price ) values:

```
id | item | price
-------------
10 | book | 20  
20 | copy | 30   
30 | pen  | 10
```

....table2 ( id, item, price) values:

```
id | item | price
-------------
10 | book | 20
10 | book | 30
```

now i if do not have a record with id-10,item-book and price-(20+30) in table 1 then i want to insert that row with sum(20+30) in  a new table ...

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: my  expected output should be  id | item | price
-------------
10 | book | 50 when sum of these two not equals the one in another table it should return the sum from table 2

Comment: updated question which is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I haven't misunderstood your requirements, this should do it:

```
 SELECT T2.ID, T2.ITEM,T2.SUMPRICE FROM 
 (SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table1 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) AS T1
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table2 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) AS T2
 ON T1.ID = T2.id  AND T1.item = T2.item WHERE T1.SUMPRICE <> T2.SUMPRICE
```

If your 3rd table is already created you could just use an [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) statement. Otherwise you could use a [SELECT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)  like this:

```
SELECT T2.ID, T2.ITEM,T2.SUMPRICE as price into table3 FROM 
(SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table1 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) AS 
T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table2 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) AS 
T2
ON T1.ID = T2.id  AND T1.item = T2.item WHERE T1.SUMPRICE <> T2.SUMPRICE
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT 1**
In the case that you want to get all the unmatched rows, that is:

1. Rows from table 2 where the id, item *or* price don't match simultenously with a given row in table 1
2. Rows from table 2 where none of their columns match simultenously with a given row in table 1

You could use the [EXCEPT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm) statement, for example:

```
(SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table2 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) 
 EXCEPT
(SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table1 GROUP BY ID, ITEM)
```

This returns:

```
ID   ITEM                 SUMPRICE
---- -------------------- -----------
10   book                 50
```

Comment: hi your query works when when the two columns matches and the price column differs but i want to insert record when i have column where none of the column matches with present one

Comment: Ok, take a look at the EDIT 1 section. That may be it. By the way, when you say in your comment _none of the column matches_ you mean that any one column doesn't match or literally none of them?

Comment: brilliant really appreciate that (SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table2 GROUP BY ID, ITEM) 
 EXCEPT
(SELECT ID, ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS SUMPRICE FROM table1 GROUP BY ID, ITEM)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT T2.id,T2.item,T2.Price as Table2_Price,T1.Price as Table1_Price FROM (
SELECT id,Item,Sum(Price) as Price
FROM Table2
Group BY id,Item ) AS T2 LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T1
ON T1.Item = T2.Item and T1.ID = T2.ID
```

After reading your comments *`when sum of these two not equals the one in another table it should return the sum from table 2`* , you are asking for the following logic

```
SELECT T2.id,T2.Item, CASE WHEN T1.Price IS NULL THEN T2.Price 
                           WHEN T2.Price <> T1.Price THEN T2.Price 
                           ELSE T1.Price END as Price FROM (
SELECT id,Item,Sum(Price) as Price
FROM Table2
Group BY id,Item ) AS T2 LEFT JOIN Table1 AS T1
ON T1.Item = T2.Item and T1.ID = T2.ID
```

But this logic isn't useful, because if `Sum(Table2_price) <> Table1_Price` you want to select `Sum(Table2_price)` else when `Sum(Table2_price) = Table1_Price` you want `Table1_Price` !! So you want to always choose `Sum(Table2_Price)`

Comment: my actual requirement is when i am not getting a record in table 1 which equal to table 2( table 2 may contain contains same type of rows separated by price) then i want the -1 * sum of price column in table 2 beacuse it is not matching with table 1.

Comment: @KalyanVarma please check the first query i suggested and give me a reply, i updated my answer